# Value of a put > strike?

Tags: derivatives

I dont understand why the value of a put will be greater than the strike. Is this human error? Weatherford had been delisted and the price of the underlying OTC is 0.05 at the moment. Its a 0.50 Put 6/21 and market value is 0.52 making no sense to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: The theoretical price is 0.5 but if you want to buy it they are overcharging you a little (and probably the reverse if you try to sell it).

Comment: Welcome to Quantitative Finance. What's the put's spread (bid x ask)? Could this be a stale bid? Since the underlying has been delisted, could there be some barrier to executing the put?